# unifying query language for accessing data from heterogeneous database

Tags: java, database

In my current project, I am trying to unify query language for accessing heterogeneous database. Heterogeneous database means their query language for accessing data is different. For instance, SQL is a query language for accessing data from Apache Derby, while nonSQL for MongoDB.

My question is  "Is there any domain specific language, which have been proposed to unify heterogeneous databases ? "

Please feel free to direct me other efforts as well.

Comment: Till now, only Database management tools could have achieved something near to this. i.e. they can connect to different data sources and can validate the SQL or query before it is actually executing based on the underlying provider. You are proposing a big project feasibility of which is yet unknown

Comment: I don't think so. You have to write query populate engine which must be artificially intelligent enough to populate query depend upon database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite an interesting question. There is at least one proposed solution called UnQL (Unstructured Data Query Language) - http://www.couchbase.com/press-releases/unql-query-language.
I suppose out of the box UnQL will work at least for CouchDB and SQLite. This just seems to be a great step ahead.

Personally I would say such a task seems to be a tricky one because of the conceptual differences between structured and unstructured data approaches. Anyway, it should be relatively easy to develop such a DSL for a well defined SQL and NoSQL data models used by a certain application.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [Hibernate OGM](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/ogm.html), which aims to generalize JPQL to NoSQL databases.

From their web page:

> Hibernate Object/Grid Mapper (OGM) aims at providing Java Persistence (JPA) support for NoSQL solutions. It reuses Hibernate Core's engine but persists entities into a NoSQL data store instead of a relational database. It reuses the Java Persistence Query Language (JP-QL) to search their data.

I don't tried it out for myself, so I cannot say how usefull it is.

Answer (score 1):

[JSONiq](http://jsoniq.org) can process data from different SQL and NoSQL products.
[The open source implementation of JSONiq](http://www.zorba-xquery.com) has connectors for Couchbase, Oracle NoSQL, SQLite, and JDBC.
For instance, the following slidedeck showcase the same query being executed on both Couchbase and MongoDB: https://speakerdeck.com/wcandillon/jsoniq-the-sql-of-nosql

Answer (score 0):

[SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) is a W3C-standardized query language that works on top of an abstract data model ([RDF](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/)), rather than a specific type of database, which makes it very suitable as an enabler for heterogeneous database querying.

[Implementations of SPARQL exist](http://www.w3.org/wiki/SparqlImplementations) on top of various NoSQL databases, including native RDF databases (often referred to as triplestores), as well as on top of relational databases.